# How to connect to an excel file from a .net web application using vb

Tags: .net, vb.net, xlsx

I have a .net web application and in that I want to access an xlsx file, Am able to access file by giving full path. It is working fine in local system, but once after deploying in server am not able to access the file. How to get it done in server.

Comment: Show us some of your code? How it's look like now?

Comment: SorceFile = "C:\DB\DashboardDB.xlsx"
If System.IO.File.Exists(SorceFile) Then

----

Else

---

End if
my cod is like this

Comment: If you want to access your file from web application first you must upload this file to teh server to. It's impossible to open via web directly from your computer.

Comment: file is available in the same path in server as well

Comment: So maybe user on which web application is started doesn't have access to that location, do you have some errors?

Comment: any progress? Did you solve the problem?

Comment: No. I give the admin access to the IIS user and i give full access to that user for that folder too then also i am not able to resolve it

Comment: Try with`try{..}catch(Exception ex){..}` and log error than you will know what happens